# 302 error from (IE only) in the javaee project with jitsso deployed in tomcat RHEL vm

Tags: internet-explorer, tomcat, jakarta-ee, single-sign-on, http-status-code-302

My Web application uses jitsso. When I deployed it in to the Tomcat 7 in RHEL VM .  It runs smoothly in the chrome and firefox.  But, It show 302 error in the Internet explorer . Initially .In the localhost it works for all the browser.

Comment: Please learn about how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: 302 [isn't an error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302).